# pydrive how to fetch spreadsheet result into json

Tags: python, dataframe, google-drive-api, pydrive, pygsheets

[image]Hi, how can i get the json format of my google spreadsheet using pydrive. i can already see the result in console using print but when i try to return it always giving me errors "Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable"

Answer (score 0):

hello i just found out an answer to my problem. and i only add this small lines.

[image]